# Select the first row and merge into a data set with Proc Sql

Tags: sql, sas

The problem is under SAS 9.1.3, with two datasets: A and B.

Set A is the main data set contains the dates and names.

```
data Aa;
    input date name $  ;
    datalines;
    20120102 A 
    20110102 B 
    20120102 C 
    20110102 A 
    20120102 B 
    20110102 C 
    ;
```

Set B contains data I want to merge to set A.

```
data B;
    input date name $  rate;
    datalines;
    20120101 A 0.01
    20120101 B 0.02
    20120101 C 0.03
    20110101 A -0.01
    20110101 B -0.02
    20110101 C -0.03
    ;
```

I understand that there is no fetch xxx row in the SAS proc sql, hence I've added row count into set B:

```
proc sort data = b; by descending  date  name ;run;
data b1;
    set b;
    ind = _n_;
run;
```

What I want to do is to merge the latest rates from B into A.  And my proc sql is like this:

```
proc sql;
    create table new as
    select a.*,b.rate
    from Aa a left join b1 b
    on a.name = b.name and a.date>=b.date
    group by b.ind having min(b.ind)=b.ind; 
quit;
```

But my result is like this:

```
20110102 A .  

20110102 B .  

20110102 C .  

20120102 A -0.01

20120102 B -0.02 

20120102 C -0.03
```

The expected result is:

```
20110102 A -0.01  

20110102 B -0.02  

20110102 C -0.03  

20120102 A 0.01

20120102 B 0.02 

20120102 C 0.03
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add a row counter to B, you aren't doing a side-by-side merge anyhow.

I think this works (I rename Aa to A):

```
proc sql;
create table C as
select _A.date, _A.name, b.rate from (
    select date, name, max(b_date) as b_date from (
        select a.*, b.rate, b.date as b_date from a
        left join b
        on a.name = b.name
           and a.date gt b.date)
    group by name, date) _A 
    left join b
    on _A.name=b.name
    and _A.b_Date=b.date;
quit;
```

The basic concept is first construct your cartesian join, ie, the join of all possible rows where A.date > B.date, and then filter down based on the row with the smallest difference in dates to figure out which row/date has the rate you need.  Then join back to the B table to get the rate itself.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer,and sorry that I didn't make my question very clear. The original problem is that there are many matches with names between two datasets, but I just want the latest one rate (in all a.date>=b.date, then use maximum(b.date) one ) in those matched data to merged into a.  And there is only one rate for a given name and date.

Comment: Right, so I select in the inner query all possible records that have A.date > b.date, and then in the outer query filter to the one with the smallest A.date - B.date value (thus, the max(b.date) record).

Comment: If you're confused, run just the inner query first, and see what that generates - in this case, 9 rows (it matches the A 20120102 row to both B rows and the A 20110102 row to the one B row).  Then the outer query removes the extra A 20120102 row.  This might not be the optimum solution if you have a huge number of possibly matching rows, but it's a simple one.

Comment: The idea of "having min(date-b_date);" is brilliant, and the code is really simple as well. The question is that the "max(rate)" at the outer query will simply chose the maximum rate when there are many matches. If I changed the rate in b (negative to positive, and positive to negative), then the code will return all the positive rates.

Comment: Ah, good point.  I think then that you may need to consider this query as picking the b_date only, and then join it back to A.  Edited answer to include this.  (Actually can use max(b.rate) instead of using the HAVING clause, since we're doing this.)